# Why wav:source doesn't work in my script but it works when I enter it directly from the terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, instruments, measurement

I'm doing a school assignment and I need some help. I have to connect to hp 54600 oscilloscope and collect data from both channels and then do some measurements. But I tried every command I could think off, and it still does measurements from channel1, no matter what I do. It changes the source to channel2 when I do it directly from the terminal, but it doesn't do anything when i run my program. So, I will send you my basic code and I hope you can tell me what to add to solve this.

**

```
import serial, time, sys
from pylab import *
hp = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',460800,timeout = 5)
kanal=int(sys.argv[1])
if kanal==1:
    hp.write('wav:sour chan1\r')
else:
    hp.write('wav:sour chan2\r')
hp.write('+eoi:0\r')
hp.write('+eos:13\r')
hp.write('+a:5\r')
time.sleep(1)
hp.write('wav:form asc\r')
time.sleep(1)
hp.write('wav:poin 5000\r')
time.sleep(1)
hp.write('wav:data?\r')
x = hp.readline()
x = x.replace('\x00','')
x = x[10:-1]
x = x.split(',')
xx = []
for entry in x:
    xx.append(float(entry))
np.save(str(kanal),xx)
plot(xx,'m-',linewidth=2)
show()
hp.close()
```

**

Comment: https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: According to [the HP documentation](https://www.keysight.com/main/redirector.jspx?action=ref&cname=EDITORIAL&ckey=678053&lc=eng&cc=US&nfr=-32417.536881117.00), there should be a colon between `wav` and `source`, but a space between `source` and `channel`.  Try `WAVEFORM:SOURCE CHANNEL2`

Comment: I think I tried that too, but I'm out of options so I'll try it again today. Thank you:)